# Python function squaring odd numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting the following error 
"not all arguments converted during string formatting"
I have the following code:
The error is pointing at this part of the code

```
if num % 2 == 0:
```

```
def squareodd(num):
    list = []
    for i in num:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            list.append(i**2)
    return list

squareodd("1,2,3,4,5,6")
```

The expected output is supposed to square all odd numbers

Comment: `map(int, num.split(","))`

Comment: The argument you're passing to the function is a string. That becomes `num`. Then you iterate through `num` with `i`. So `i` is a one-character string, not a number, when you attempt `i % 2`. Actually you're not even doing that, you're doing `num%2`, which makes less sense.

Comment: you are providing string to function instead of list

Comment: That is because `("1,2,3,4,5,6")` is a string. Simply switching to (1,2,3,4,5,6) would work/

Comment: Also, `i` would be `','` every other iteration.

Comment: Tom ake it clear you need two pairs of brackets squareodd((1,2,3,4,5,6))

Comment: Also you would need to change `num % 2` to `i % 2`, and change `lst` to an actual list.

Comment: FWIW: `[i**2 for i in range(1, 7) if i % 2 == 0]`…

Answer (score 3):

```
def squareodd(num):
    #lst = () # 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
    lst = []
    for i in num:
        # if num % 2 == 0: # you are trying to use the % (modulo) operator on the list instead on item of list 
        if i % 2 == 0:
            lst.append(i**2)
    return lst

print (squareodd([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split your string by comma and the convert it to an int object then iterate.

**Ex:**

```
def squareodd(num):
    lst = []
    for i in map(int, num.split(",")):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            lst.append(i**2)
    return lst

print(squareodd("1,2,3,4,5,6"))
```

Comment: It'd be a lot more logical to send a list of numbers instead of trying to deal with the string.

Comment: That's true. But OP has a list of string comma separated for some reason...

Comment: so than hey could do the split on caller side